# Solar potential or irradiation GIS data for India

Tags: data, india, solar-radiation

I am looking for solar irradiation data for India in a gis format. Like the ones on the link below:
http://www.arcgis.com/apps/OnePane/basicviewer/index.html?appid=bf886ca471a54e2c9127a54f60d4ca27

Answer (score 2):

Second top hit for "solar irradiation data in India" gives this:
http://mnre.gov.in/sec/solar-assmnt.htm

There's an online map, data files and also contacts you could talk to. They appear to have been part funded by the U.S. National Renewable Energy Laboratory - who I think are the originators of the ArcGIS link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Solar irradiation data can be found and downloaded here:
http://www.nrel.gov/international/ra_india.html

Answer (score 0):

***Global Solar Atlas*** offers raster data as long-term yearly averages (for India calculated for a period 1999-2015) for six parameters (including global horizontal irradiation - GHI, photovoltaic power potential PVOUT, etc.). Data is available as GeoTIFF or ESRI ASCII Grid, 30 arcsec (~1 km) resolution, LatLon WGS84 coordinate system.

Terms is [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) (so kind of free data), copyrighted by The World Bank and provided by Solargis.

Download page
[http://**globalsolaratlas.info**/downloads/india](http://globalsolaratlas.info/downloads/india)  or 
 [https://**solargis.com**/maps-and-gis-data/download/india](https://solargis.com/maps-and-gis-data/download/india)

Data for other countries or global data layers are available to download, too.